# Symfony2, Assetic, Compass, and SASS

Tags: php, symfony, sass, assetic, symfony-2.8

I've been looking all over for a good, recent tutorial on how to hook up SASS within symfony (specifically 2.8). It looks like there are no tutorials newer that 2011. Is this because there's some reason I shouldn't be using SASS with Symfony? If there is a way to set this up easily, could someone point me in the right direction. I have Compass and SASS installed on my machine (along with the assetic bundle for Symfony).

Comment: This is somehow explained in the cookbook chapter ["How to Use Assetic for Asset Management"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#filters). But I'd recommend to use Gulp over Assetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony 2.8 no longer includes Assetic by default, but there are [instructions available to install and enable it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html). (Basically: add `symfony/assetic-bundle` to your `composer.json` and add the necessary configuration.)

The [best practice](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html) these days seems to be to use frontend tools specifically focused for frontend development. (The Symfony best practices document specifically recommends GruntJS, but it's not the only solution.)

Comment: I've got assetic installed. I just didn't know if there was some special configuration step I needed to go through. I guess I just put my .scss files in an AppBundle/Resources/scss folder and have compass write the compiled version to AppBundle/Resources/css and do assetic:dump?

Comment: The default for `assetic.write_to` is the web directory, and you would normally `{% stylesheets ... output='css/compiled/*.css' %}`, so your css files will wind up in `web/css/compiled/`. You can have it output to any other location that works better for you, though, but the compiled products go in `web`, not in `src`.

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand this write. I can put my scss files in `AppBundle/Resources/scss` and `assetic:dump` will compile that to css in the `web/css/compiled` folder? If that's correct do I need to tell assetic about the scss folder?

Comment: That's correct. You tell Assetic about where the files are as part of the stylesheet tag: `{% stylesheets output='css/compiled/*.css' filter='sass' '@AppBundle/Resources/scss/your.scss' %}`.

Comment: @ LoneWolfPR  in case you are still interested, there is a modern tutorial in the official Symfony Documentation explaining how to use Assetic to manage CSS, SASS and JavaScript assets: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/php.html